# ¿Parte de mi codigo solo se aplica a 2 de 5 elementos que quería que afectase?

Tags: javascript

tengo un pequeño problema. Tengo esta parte de código:

```
var LibrosXestante= 3;

var book = [{
        title: "The Giver 1",
        autor: "Manueh",
        stars: 4
    },
    {
        title: "The Giver 2",
        Autor: "Jesu",
        stars: 3
    },
    {
        title: "The Giver 3",
        autor: "KIKO",
        stars: 1
    },
    {
        title: "The Giver 4",
        Autor: "jaimie",
        stars: 5
    },
    {
        title: "The Giver 5",
        Autor: "jijon",
        stars: 4
}];

// Pintar las estanterías
var y = 140;    //Posición de la primera estantería.

for (var i = 0; i < book.length/LibrosXestante; i++) {
    fill(173, 117, 33);
    rect(0, y, width, 10);
    y = y + 150;    //bajar la posición de la estantería
}


//Variable para contar los libros impresos
var booksPrinted = 0;

//Función para pintar libro
var pintarLibro = function(xBook,yBook) {
    fill(214, 255, 219);
    rect(10 + xBook, yBook, 90, 115); 
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text(book[i].title, 15 + xBook, yBook+5, 60, 100);
    text(book[i].autor, 15 + xBook, yBook+35, 60, 100);
    //Si no hemos llegado al máximo de libros por estante sumamos uno
    if(booksPrinted<LibrosXestante){
        booksPrinted++;
    }
};

//Función para pintar las estrellas
var pintarEstrellas = function(i,yStars,xStars){
    for (var k = 0; k < book[i].stars; k++) {
        image(getImage("cute/Star"), (xStars + k * 15), yStars, 20, 30);
    }
};

var yBook = 25;
var xBook = 0;
var yStars = 102;
var xStars = 15;

// draw books
for (var i = 0; i < book.length; i++) {
    //Si hemos llegado al máximo de libros impresos saltamos de estante 
    //y reinicializamos las variables
    if(booksPrinted>=LibrosXestante){
        yBook = yBook + 150;
        xBook = 0;
        yStars = yStars + 150;
        xStars = 15;
        //establecemos libros impresos para la nueva estantería
        booksPrinted = 0;
    }
    pintarLibro(xBook,yBook);
    pintarEstrellas(i,yStars,xStars);
    xStars = xStars + 100;
    xBook = xBook + 100;
}
```

He estado haciendo algunos cambios, y a la hora de añadir un autor en los objetos del array book. Al imprimirlo solo me sale en los libros 1 y 3 ¿alguien sabe porque? dejo foto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al crear los libros en tu variable book, tienen la propiedad Autor (A mayuscula) en lugar de autor (a minuscula).

Cuando añades el texto accedes a la propiedad asi:

```
book[i].autor
```

Tenlo en cuenta, las propiedades y las variables en general suelen ser sensibles a las mayusculas y minusculas.

Comment: Tienes razón! No me había dado cuenta, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada, si te sirvió, por favor, recuerda marcar la respuesta como válida.